# DataGridView: Override Scrollbar Style

Tags: winforms, user-interface, scrollbars

Im using `WinForms` and the `DataGridView`.

Is there a way to Style for the `Scrollbars` to a custom color/appearance.

I have been looking for a Flat appearance.